# Error al conectarme a una BD de Mysql. Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto

Tags: c#, mysql

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es un simple metodo de conexion en c#, pero al momento de que quiero hacer la conexion con mi Base de datos me marca el siguiente error:

> Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

Codigo donde Ejecuto los Metodos de conexion.

```
    Base_de_Datos.Conexion conn = new Base_de_Datos.Conexion();
    Base_de_Datos.Conexion myconection = new Base_de_Datos.Conexion();
    connection = conn.iniciarBD();
    aprobar = myconection.OpenConnection();
```

La variable connection obtiene todos los parametros de conexion y el metodo aprobar obtiene si se establecio una conexion o no. para poder mandar diversos mensajes.

Metodo para hacer conexion.

```
    public MySqlConnection iniciarBD()
    {
        server = "localhost";
        database = "presupuesto";
        uid = "root";
        password = "";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
        database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        return connection;

    }
```

Metodo para saber si me eh conectado.

```
    public bool OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Close();
            connection.Open(); ---- Aqui sale el error
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            //When handling errors, you can your application's response based 
            //on the error number.
            //The two most common error numbers when connecting are as follows:
            //0: Cannot connect to server.
            //1045: Invalid user name and/or password.
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    MessageBox.Show("No se pudo conectar al servidor. Contacta con el administrador");
                    break;

                case 1045:
                    MessageBox.Show("Contraseña o usario Invalidos, porfavor intentelo de nuevo");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Podrías indicar en que linea del codigo te salta el error o adjuntar una captura?

Comment: @Sam.God  en la linea de connection.Open();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya localice el Error, era algo muy sencillo de hacer.

Como mandaba llamar a mi metodo de `iniciarBD()` para agregar su return a una variable y luego hacia el metodo de `OpenConnection()` que tambien necesitaba una cadena de conectividad de Mysql. pues solo agregue lo el metodo de `iniciarBD()`, para que el metodo .open pudiera abrir algo que existiera.

```
        iniciarBD();
        try
        {
            connection.Close();
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
```